# How to make UIImageView load retina and non-retina images

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, retina-display

I'm new in iOS programming and I don't know how to make UIImageView load content depending on the screen that is running the app. In my case i have a 100 frames animation. Is possible to scale the images for non-retina  displays (the images are in 640x960 resolution) automatically using code? Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Just add normal images at your project (image1.png, image2.png, ...) and your retina versions (image1@2x.png, image2@2x.png, ...). The retina versions must have "@2x" appended at end of the name.

Just use the versions without "@2x" in your code, and the Xcode will do the rest. Additionally, you can import just "@2x" versions, use image without "@2x" in your code and iOS will downsample automatically in non-retina devices.

Comment: Ok, thanks! But I can't run the animation on my iPhone 3GS, when it loads the images crashes. On the simulator it runs. I can't know if with a retina iDevice would work because i don't have one.

Comment: It's memory problem as you have 100 frames to load and then animate so 3GS device will have some low memory issue. Same type issue I have faced with my app too. Then I have to load images partially ie have to load image in 10-10 image bunches :)

Comment: Yes it's memory problem... How do I release the UIimageview when I return back to the previous view (it's a navigation controller based app). thanks!

Comment: If you are using ARC, your UIImageView will be released automatically. If not, you can use     viewDidUnload { [yourImageView release]; }